# ansible - playbook error ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set

Tags: ansible

New to ansible: trying a playbook, in which there is 1 task and 1 pretask. The task is copying a file which gets executed successfully. The pretask is checking for homebrew and if not present installed. This is throwing me this error.

**ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set**

I have already set the hosts value in top of the playbook as localhost at i am using only local host.
I have pasted the entire playbook here:

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - copy: 
      src: "~/.master.testconfig" 
      dest: "~/.testconfig"

- pre_tasks:
   - name: Ensure Homebrew is Installed
     stat:
      path: /usr/local/bin/brew
      register: homebrew_check

   - name: Fail If Homebrew Is Not Installed
     fail: 
       msg: Homebrew is missing.. Install from http://brew.sh/
       when:
         - not homebrew_check.stat.exists

   - name: Installing Homebrew
     shell: /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
     when:
       - not homebrew_check.stat.exists
       - install_homebrew_if_missing
```

Output:
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit
localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [copy] *****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to syntax error: You don't need `-` for `pre_tasks`. Another issue is that indentation is incorrect.

The correct syntax would be:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - copy: 
        src: "~/.master.testconfig" 
        dest: "~/.testconfig"
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Ensure Homebrew is Installed
      stat:
        path: /usr/local/bin/brew
        register: homebrew_check

    - name: Fail If Homebrew Is Not Installed
      fail: 
        msg: Homebrew is missing.. Install from http://brew.sh/
      when: not homebrew_check.stat.exists

    - name: Installing Homebrew
      shell: /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
      when:
        - not homebrew_check.stat.exists
        - install_homebrew_if_missing
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I just had to to correct register indentation to align with stat: Just a small question this part is not getting executed name: Installing Homebrew it fails and stops with the execution actually i want to Install homebrew in the pretask if not present after the failure message

Comment: @user1403505 the condition is right. is Ruby present in the system? what error are you facing?